# How do i run Ruby script from command line ?

Tags: ruby

I've a file, which I can run from command line using:

```
ruby filename.rb
```

Which outputs:

```
12345
```

A different script containing:

```
def hi() 
puts "hello"
end
```

does not return anything when I run it from the command-line.

How do I run this from the command line?

Comment: This is an extremely elementary problem covered by tutorials. Where have you searched and why didn't that information help? Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @theTinMan - yes it is, as i am beginner, and searched through tutorials. but did not find this specific problem.

Comment: Perhaps a quick search of the internet using `ruby call a method`?

Comment: @theTinMan - i am working on this tutorial [link](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/2/) - as they go though the example and change code, it is hard to manage on "irb" console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in `filename.rb`:

```
def hi()
    puts "hello"
end

hi
```

Then run your code in the command line: with `ruby filename.rb`

Comment: @kasper_341 If you're in `irb`, you need to exit it using `exit` then run the code in my answer. Make sure you're in the correct directory in your command line.

Comment: And you did save the file before running the script? Just trying to cover all bases here.

Comment: thanks for your help. it worked now. may b a typo error

Answer (score 1):

Add puts `hi("John")` to the bottom of the method:

```
def hi(name)
  puts "hello"
end

puts hi("John")
```

Where "John" is whatever name you want it to be.

Then just run it as usual, `ruby yourfilename.rb`